# JSPDF downloads blank pdf file first time, but next it downloads proper

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, jspdf

I am trying to export svg diagram to pdf using JSPF library.
Problem is when user click to download first time it gives blank pdf file
But second time it generates correct file.
Below is my code, please help i am trying from last two days.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svg);

    canvg(canvas, svgString);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'ledger');
    pdf.setFontSize(10);
    pdf.text(35, 25, "Google Cloud Craft");

    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 50, 40);
    pdf.save(projectIdName + '.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to solve it, forgot a basic thing, to handle callback function of canvg function.

```
canvg(canvas, svgString,{
        renderCallback: function(){
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'ledger');
            pdf.setFontSize(10);
            pdf.text(35, 25, "CLouditect");

            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 50, 40);
            pdf.save(projectIdName + '.pdf');
            $('#background-svg').remove();
        }
    });
```

the problem was canvg was not able to create full canvas, so there is a callback function called renderCallback which is called after canvas rendering is finished.
after that you can save it properly.

Refer other options also here https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg